# PHP / SQL - UPDATE, perfome and return success but no update in db has been made

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php / sql request:

It is connected successfully and run update successfully (returning success msg), but in phpMyAdmin, the database has not been updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 

{ // Connect and Test MySQL and specific DB (return $dbSuccess = T/F)

            $hostname = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";             
            $databaseName = "db_test";    
            $dbConnected = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
            $dbSelected = mysql_select_db($databaseName,$dbConnected);

            $dbSuccess = true;
            if ($dbConnected) {
                if (!$dbSelected) {
                    echo "DB connection FAILED<br /><br />";
                    $dbSuccess = false;
                }       
            } else {
                echo "MySQL connection FAILED<br /><br />";
                $dbSuccess = false;
            }
}  

//   Execute code ONLY if connections were successful   
if ($dbSuccess) {       

        // SQL to change country value from UK to United Kingdom 
        $company_SQLupdate = "UPDATE tCompany SET ";            
        $company_SQLupdate .= "COUNTRY = 'United Kingdom' ";            
        $company_SQLupdate .= "WHERE COUNTRY = 'UK' ";          
        if (mysql_query($company_SQLupdate))  { 
            echo "UPDATE tCompany.COUNTRY - SUCCESSFUL.<br /><br />";
        } else {
            echo "UPDATE tCompany.COUNTRY - FAILED.<br /><br />";
        }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
if (mysql_query($company_SQLupdate))  { 
    echo "UPDATE tCompany.COUNTRY - SUCCESSFUL.<br /><br />";
} else {
    echo "UPDATE tCompany.COUNTRY - FAILED.<br /><br />";
}
```

to

```
if (mysql_query($company_SQLupdate))  { 
    echo "UPDATE tCompany.COUNTRY - SUCCESSFUL.<br /><br />";
} else {
    var_dump(mysql_error());
}
```

to see the error

**EDIT 1**

```
select * 
from tCompany             
WHERE COUNTRY = 'UK'
```

to see if there records with `COUNTRY = 'UK'`

Comment: @Pete such query set the value of the specified fields if found anything. probably in your case there are no records with `COUNTRY = 'UK'`

Comment: @pete just after this line `if ($dbSuccess) { `

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\update.php on line 29` - does it mean there are any COUNTRY = "UK" ?

Comment: you shoul write somethisn like this: `mysql_query("select * from Company WHERE COUNTRY = 'UK'")` and then fetch records like [here](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or just run thet sql in phpMyAdmin just to see rsult

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you have records with `country = 'UK'` in the DB?

you could change your success message showing the complete query, then try to execute that statement in phpMyAdmin and see if the modifications are appearing.

Comment: How can I display full query?

Comment: change `echo "UPDATE tCompany.COUNTRY - SUCCESSFUL.<br /><br />";` into `echo "$company_SQLupdate - SUCCESSFUL.<br /><br />";`

Comment: This is the first thing to try -- UPDATE statements are successful even if they don't affect any rows. To see if this is the case, you can use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to see the number of rows affected by the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure that column names are uppercase letters?

I am talking about "COUNTRY".

Sure it's not "country"?

Comment: It is Country - so is wrong. What does it them return success?

Comment: Because where clause finds 0 rows - and updates 0 rows accordingly - and reports success. Message is, as i recall - Update OK, 0 rows changed. :)

Comment: @Pete Are you doing this on a Windows machine?